# Calculate right, up and view vector from at and eye vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdi, win32gui

I am trying to make a WorldToView matrix and for that I need to calculate the right(r),up(u) and view vectors(v).

I know the eye vector is `eye(0,0,0)` and at vector is `at(0,0,-1)`; then by:

`v= normalise(at-eye);` view vector v will be (0,0,-1)

How do I get r and u vectors?

I know that:

```
r=normalise(v X u);
u=normalise(r X v);
```

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ or Win32?

Comment: Not in particular but I am making a 3D renderer using c++ and GDI so it is related.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: GDI and some classes from ogre3D, namely Matrix4, Vector4 and Vector3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have enough information at the moment - you don't know which way up your viewer is oriented, it could be anything. You probably want to specify an up vector, e.g. `(0,1,0)`, and then calculate `r` using the equation.

Note, for what it's worth, that `gluLookAt`, the GLU function that does the equivalent of what you're trying to do, takes three parameters, not two - namely an eye vector, an at vector and an up vector. You're missing the up vector, hence why you're running into difficulties.

Comment: Thanks Stuart (and for the explanation)